# Please explain these RLC transient equations

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxGPCZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

From my book

Assume the capacitor is charged to a voltage V0, and then at t = 0, the switch is closed.
\begin{gather*}
\frac{1}{C}\int Idt+IR+L\frac{dI}{dt} =0\\
\frac{d^{2} I}{dt^{2}} +\frac{R}{L}\frac{dI}{dt} +\frac{1}{LC} I=0\\
 \end{gather*}
select

\begin{gather*}
I=I_{0} e^{\alpha t}\\
\end{gather*}

substitute into the differential equation gives.
\begin{gather*}
\alpha ^{2} +\frac{R}{L} \alpha +\frac{1}{LC} =0\\
\alpha _{1} =-\frac{R}{2L} +\sqrt{\frac{R^{2}}{4L^{2}} -\frac{1}{LC}}\\
\alpha _{2} =-\frac{R}{2L} -\sqrt{\frac{R^{2}}{4L^{2}} -\frac{1}{LC}}\\
I=I_{1} e^{\alpha _{1} t} +I_{2} e^{\alpha _{2} t}\\
\end{gather*}
In this case
the constants can be evaluated from a knowledge of I(0) and dI/dt(0). Since the current in the inductor
was zero for t < 0, and since it cannot change abruptly, we know that:
\begin{gather*}
I( 0) =0\\
\end{gather*}

The initial voltage across the inductor is the same as across the capacitor, so that:

\begin{gather*}
I_{1} =-I_{2} =\frac{V_{0}}{( \alpha _{1} +\alpha _{2}) L}\\
\end{gather*}
The solution for the current in the series RLC circuit is thus:

\begin{gather*}
I=\frac{V_{0}}{( \alpha _{1} -\alpha _{2}) L}\left( e^{\alpha _{1} t} -e^{\alpha _{2} t}\right)\\\end{gather*}
Case 1: Overdamped
For R2 > 4L/C, the quantity under the square root is positive, and both values of α are negative with |
α2| > |α1|. The solution is the sum of a slowly decaying positive term and a more rapidly decaying
negative term of equal initial magnitude. An important limiting
case is the one in which R2 >> 4L/C. In that limit, the square root can be approximated as:

\begin{gather*}
\sqrt{\frac{R^{2}}{4L^{2}} -\frac{1}{LC}} =\frac{R}{2L}\sqrt{1-\frac{4L}{R^{2} C}} \approx \frac{R}{2L} -\frac{1}{RC}\\
\alpha _{1} =-\frac{1}{RC},
\alpha _{2} =-\frac{R}{L}\\
I\approx \frac{V_{0}}{R}\left( e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} -e^{\frac{-Rt}{L}}\right)
\end{gather*}

---

How does this equation  is estimated?

\begin{gather*}
\frac{R}{2L}\sqrt{1-\frac{4L}{R^{2} C}} \approx \frac{R}{2L} -\frac{1}{RC}\\
\end{gather*}
I think it should be right?
\begin{gather*}
\alpha _{2} =-\frac{R}{L} +\frac{1}{RC}\\
\end{gather*}

But if

\begin{gather*}
\alpha _{2} =-\frac{R}{L}\\
\end{gather*}

Current should be
\begin{gather*}
I\approx \frac{V_{0} RC}{-L+R^{2} C}\left( e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} -e^{\frac{-Rt}{L}}\right)\\\end{gather*}

Comment: Does this result pass your mental test criteria for current at t=0 or just after t=0?

Comment: If not , find your error.